# Do every images save in res/drawable folder?

Tags: android, android-drawable

I want to ask about Android drawable folder. Is there a maximum number for images count ? Or every image will be saved in the folder ? So, that makes a complexity, isn't it ? I tried to group images folder by folder in res/drawable, but it didn't work. So, how can the big apps that has many images handle that ? Thanks.

Comment: Image can also be in mipmap folders

Comment: @AlLelopath **NO**. `mipmap` is **ONLY** for the app icon. **NOTHING ELSE**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all local image assets are saved in `res/drawable/`.

Usually, developers will employ a naming convention to help keep resources organised, e.g. prefixing with screen/activity names.

This will allow you quickly search (Cmd-Shift-O/Ctrl-Shift-N) for drawables used on a particular screen.

---

You can also create multiple resource directories (I don't think it's as common) but you need to manually add them to your sourceset in build.gradle:

```
sourceSets {
    main.res.srcDirs += 'src/main/res-mobile'
    main.res.srcDirs += 'src/main/res-tv'
    main.res.srcDirs += 'src/main/res-android-tv'
}
```

https://antonioleiva.com/android-multiple-resource-folders/